# Dplyr equivalent to CASE WHEN IS NOT NULL?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking to create some logic that would look as such in SQL

```
CASE WHEN COLUMN IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

How would this look like within the mutate verb using dplyr?

I was thinking

```
mutate(Bucket = case_when(!is.na(COLUMN) ~ 1,0))
```

Would this work

Comment: It is essential to share a reproducible piece of your data set by means of `dput(head(data))` so that you will have better chances of getting relevant answers to help you with your question.

Comment: you could also do `mutate(Bucket = case_when(!is.na(COLUMN) ~ 1, T ~ 0))` if you want to use `case_when`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use `if_else` here:

```r
mutate(Bucket = if_else(!is.na(COLUMN), 1, 0))
```

The `case_when` function would be better suited to a SQL `CASE` expression having *more* than one logical branch.

Comment: yeah its just one logical branch so this solves the problem, thank you !